# «Двенадцать ночи»

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика

Так нормально говорить? Как-то режет слух мне...

Comment: А как можно сказать лучше? Разве что "полночь".

Comment: Ну да, полночь. Кто это отменил голос за вопрос?)

Comment: Артем, хороший у вас вопрос, а я за него еще не проголосовала.  Голосую сейчас.

Answer (score 4):

Вроде бы нормальное сочетание. Так и говорят, и пишут.

Большой толковый словарь ([Грамота.ру](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic?word=%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x)):

> **ДВЕНАДЦАТЬ,** -и; ***числ. колич.*** <...> Количество 12. ***Д. часов ночи.***

КАРТАСЛОВ.РУ:
[Предложения со словосочетанием «двенадцать ночи»](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8);
[Предложения со словосочетанием «двенадцать часов ночи»](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C+%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2+%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8).

*Довольно часто меня здесь можно найти и в десять, и в одиннадцать, и **в двенадцать ночи**, потому что рабочий день у меня не нормирован*
(Владимир Войнович, Хочу быть честным, 1962).
*Ну мы с ней поцапались слегка – в семь вечера начали и **до двенадцати ночи** грызлись* (Дмитрий Емец, Таня Гроттер и молот Перуна, 2003).
*Они показывали уже почти **двенадцать ночи**, оказалось, что мы разговаривали с журналистом больше часа* (Марина Серова, Город семи королей, 2008).

Comment: А мне не очень нравится.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Ну да, мне не приходилось так говорить. Если и уж хочется или необходимо произнести час, то я бы сказал без слов "часов" и "ночи"/"дня":  *до двенадцати, почти двенадцать*, так как время суток должно быть понятно из контекста.

Answer (score 2):

Я наткнулся на то, что слово час - это от слова часть, часть суток, часть цикла. И это скорее момент времени, промежуток, период, чем цифра/число. А часы - это очень кривое название механизма, ну вот так, не все русские выражения идеальны, часы - то что показывает часть суток.

В урочный час, в недобрый час, в оговоренный час, в полночный час. Полночь - именование этого самого часа. А 12 - это какая-то цифра, число, не ясно, на самом деле к чему относящаяся и во фразу не укладывающаяся. Поэтому если говорить о времени или части времени суток, лучше называть именами, а не непонятными цифрами, тогда и слух резать не будет. Ну и если говорить цифру, то 12 ночи - это что-то вроде кальки 12 P.M., но может с немецкого, но в любом случае то есть сленг - слово без образа, не человеческий язык.

Который час - ночь на дворе, полночь. Сутки же делятся на заутреню, утро, полдень, обед, следующий период я не знаю как по-русски называется, который около 4 дня, поэтому приходится говорить: дело к вечеру, вторая половина дня. Дальше вечер, закат, сумерки, ночь.

А столкнулся, когда увидел картину Эдварда Бёрн-Джонса "The Hours", тогда я подумал, почему у нас hours это часы-механизм? и что на английском часы это ведь clock, а не часы. Ну и если думать что часы механизм, то картина не читабельна, а если думать, что часы - это части, периоды суток, то все отлично понимается: вот заутреня, утро, полдень и тд... - их символика. А без этого понимания, какие-то бабы в тогах и часы механизм - все что есть в голове.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А в Китае, например, там сутки делятся на 12 частей по 2 часа, и каждая часть называется животным - час обезьяны, или час петуха, час крысы и тд. Китайский календарь - тоже по сути часы, части года или цикла в 12 лет... То есть "12 ночи" по-китайски - час крысы/время крысы [image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почему с немецкого? Как это у нас hours механизм, не понимаю?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой про немецкий моё предположение, потому что зависит от того, кто привез механические часы. Про "the Hours", у нас картину переводят как "часы", но у меня первое что в голову приходит при слове "часы", это часы-механизм, однако, hours это совсем не часы механизм, а от слова период, часть. Вот я и предположил, что час скорее всего производная от часть, ну либо указание на промежуток времени, любой, не обязательно 60 минут. Урочный час, лихой час наста, пришел твой час - то есть какой-то определенный момент времени.

Comment: Ну и анализируя другие культуры, да и русские названия этих самых "часов"(суточных периодов), становится понятно, что тут какая-то путаница. В тоже время в английском часы и часы-механизм - это совершенно разные слова. Потому фразы "двенадцать часов ночи" и да и 12 дня, 10 утра - все они слышаться кривовато. Ну а 12 ночи - это вообще странная ситуация, а вот если называть все своими именами: на часах 10 утра - не обрубая фразу, то звучит намного лучше. Ну а для 12 ночи своё название есть - полночь. То есть 10 - просто цифра, час - часть, а утро - это дополнение, они все в отрыве от "часов"

Answer (score 2):

Я прислушалась к этой фразе, и она тоже стала резать мне слух.

***Двенадцать ночи***... А где грамматическая связь рядом стоящих слов?

А если так: ***Двенадцать часов ночи***...  Тоже плохо: количественный оборот получился, как будто часы сосчитали.

Но фраза **закрепилась** в языке и уже обозначена в словарях.

А что делать, если **все так говорят?** Коротко, удобно...

Наверное, не стоит прислушиваться, а то начинаешь воспринимать устойчивое речевое сочетание (фразеологизм?)  дословно))

Comment: Устойчивое сочетание слов(не речи) - это идиома. А фразеологизм - это фраза, звучащая, так, чтобы образ яркий создавался. " Идиомы возникают при частом употреблении сочетания, из-за утраты связей между компонентами. Обычно идиомы имеют слитное значение и в целом реализуют общую тенденцию языка к образованию простых знаков на основе составных."

Comment: Вот это смешно: "Будучи всегда достоянием одного только языка (исключение составляют так наз. «кальки» (см.)), И. является частным случаем идиотизма." Хотя, может я путаю фразеологизмы и идиомы.

Comment: https://www.techinsider.ru/popmem/1565649-uroki-russkogo-uvereny-vy-ne-znaete-chto-obshchego-u-slov-idiot-idiotizm-i-idioma/

Comment: да-да. Но фраза все равно звучит смешно, хотя это советская энциклопедия начала 20 века. Хотя идиоты - это что-то вроде отшельников, но в тоже время или изгнанники из полиса у греков. И идиот - это да, не похожий на других, выпадающий из общепринятой системы взглядов, поэтому идиот - это своего рода герой, но не протагонист и не антагонист. Ну и да, латынь - это такой извращенный греческий. А русский во многом прямой наследник греческого, а не отлатинский, поэтому латинизмы отдельно - и измы, а греческие слова, это свои собственные, родные, а не термины-латинизмы.

Comment: Хотя вот например слово люди, мне кажется имеет латинские корни, а не греческие. И это от латинского людус - играть в игры, кстати людус - это единственное число, а люди - множественное. Поэтому сразу приобретают иное звучание фразы: честной люд, людская, служилые люди и тп. Люди - это игроки, пешки, фигуры, карты особой масти и тп. Честной люд - играющие честно, честные игроки, честные подданные, то есть соблюдающие правила, права, правду.